# Install Lottie Player to Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm currently trying to implement [Lottie](https://github.com/LottieFiles/lottie-player) to my Angular web-app.

Somehow I couldn't manage to do so yet. I tried to follow the instructions from **github**, but that lead to multiple errors, as f.e.:

> lottie-player is not a known ng module.

Furthermore, I tried to install [ng-lottie](https://github.com/chenqingspring/ng-lottie) for Angular - since the original wasn't working - but this one didn't provide any option to jump to a frame or loop only to a certain frame.

Does anyone know an alternative or a way to get lottie player working?

Answer (score 16):

You can add lottie-player as a custom element schema

```
npm install --save @lottiefiles/lottie-player
```

angular.json

```
"scripts": [
          "./node_modules/@lottiefiles/lottie-player/dist/lottie-player.js"
]
```

custom.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
})
export class CustomModule { }
```

custom.component.html

```
<lottie-player src="https://assets4.lottiefiles.com/datafiles/zc3XRzudyWE36ZBJr7PIkkqq0PFIrIBgp4ojqShI/newAnimation.json"  background="transparent"  speed="1" loop  autoplay >
</lottie-player>
```

Hope this helps! and if you managed to implements it with a different approach you can help by sharing it

Answer (score 4):

theres a much simpler approach, install required packages as below

```
npm i ngx-lottie & lottie-web
```

in your app.module.ts, add

```
import { LottieModule } from 'ngx-lottie'; // add this line

export function playerFactory() { // add this line
  return import('lottie-web'); // add this line
} // add this line

@NgModule({ 
declarations: ['your component 1', 'your component 2'...],
imports: [ 
   LottieModule.forRoot({ player: playerFactory, useCache: true }) // add this line
]})
```

stop your angular server 4200 and start again using ng serve

define options in your component.ts file as

```
options: AnimationOptions = {
    path: 'add animation json file link', // download the JSON version of animation in your project directory and add the path to it like ./assets/animations/example.json
  };
```

then in your component.ts file

import the animation options module at the top of your component as

```
import { AnimationOptions } from 'ngx-lottie';
```

then in your component.html

```
<ng-lottie height="auto" [options]="options"></ng-lottie>
```

for more information on other attributes of ng-lottie tag visit
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-lottie

Comment: it has a build issue now 

https://github.com/ngx-lottie/ngx-lottie/issues/130

Comment: angular 17 has standalone components now this cant be used

Comment: The issue is fixed